# Record VGA/DVI with timecode

Tags: timecode, screen-casting, hdmi

I'd like to record presentations and lectures and then edit them after the fact. I'll use one or more camera feeds and a timecode source (either a camcorder or external source). To record the screen, I was thinking of using something like [the Blackmagic Hyperdeck Shuttle](http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/hyperdeckshuttle), but I'm not stuck on this device.

The Shuttle can record HDMI sources (great--I can record DVI or convert VGA to HDMI). However, it can only record timecode from SDI. I could convert HDMI to SDI, but then where does the timecode come from? Is there any way I can inject the timecode into my SDI stream?

Any other totally different solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cost isn't an object, I believe the higher end rack mount HyperDeck accepts an external timecode (ref in), but it's also quite a bit more expensive ($1000).

Comment: Cost is an object, but chaining HDMI to SDI converters and timecode inserters to the HyperDeck Shuttle would quickly move the system price from $340 towards $1000 as well--Thanks!

Comment: @watkipet - yeah, working with unified time code usually is expensive.  Black Magic Design at least makes it a little cheaper.